# Keeping an IAP for a users account after an upgrade from a version that had no IAPs on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have my app in the App Store, currently as a paid version, but I am making this free and bringing IAPs which unlocks some features that they had previously. For example, Free users can add only 10 entries, but IAP users can add any amount in this version that I'm developing, but on the current App Store version, they could add any amount.

If a user is upgrading from the version in the App Store to the version I'm bringing now, I immediately set a NSUserDefault "IAPSuccessful" to YES, so that the user has unlocked all of the features (because they've already purchased it).

However, if the user deletes the app and reinstalls it and clicks on the Restore button, there's nothing for them to actually restore.

How would I go about fixing this? I want to make sure the user has all of the features when they upgrade, but how do I assign the purchase to their account, so that they can restore from another device or if the app is deleted?

To clarify, if the user is on the current version 2.2 and they upgrade, they unlock all of the features of the IAP and are now on the Pro version (based on the NSUserDefaults), but if they uninstall the app and reinstall it and then click on Restore, there's nothing for them to restore because there's no "receipt" on their account, like there would be if they were a new user and they made an IAP. How do I fix this?

I'm thinking I need to invoke a purchase when the update completes, but then not "charge" the user.

In the update, I have a small image showing with a `UIButton` that just gives an indication to the updating user what the new features are. When the user clicks the `UIButton` in that Image, it sets the `NSUserDefaults` for `IAPSuccessful` to YES, so that they are on the Pro version straight away. It's not however setting an active purchase/receipt to the user's iTunes account.

I have just tried to call the `makePurchase` method in my `IAPViewController`, but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported by the in-app purchase system. The closest you can get to doing so is to have your in-app purchase product set to the "Free" price tier, and purchase it for them in the background, as you described.

Alternatively, you could save your `IAPSuccessful` flag in the user's keychain, which would prevent the flag from being cleared when deleting the app. You can enable iCloud syncing for the keychain as well, thus persisting it across the user's devices.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the response. The second approach seems favourable to me and it would make sense to implement the IAPSuccessful flag, even if the app is deleted, but do you have any guides on how to actually save that to the iCloud keychain?

Comment: Also, is it not a requirement to do some hardcore receipt validation? Been reading up on it today and it looks extremely complicated.

Comment: With the first comment, I have tried searching for ways to save a NSUserDefault to the iOS Keychain and I can't really find anything. There's a lot of posts on how to use a different technique because it's not secure, but it doesn't need to be secure in my case.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain. It makes working with the keychain as easy as NSUserDefaults

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That's perfect and really helpful. I appreciate your help with this!